# AJAX Post error like no $_POST variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm developing a part of a website that upload the content of a textarea and of an input text to a remote database, but I have a problem in the AJAX request...

my JavaScript:

```
function pubblica(pubblicato){
  htmlpuro = document.getElementById("htmlpuro").value;
  oggetto = document.getElementById("oggetto").value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "salva_doc_ajax.php",
    data: "oggetto="+oggetto+"&html="+htmlpuro+"&pubblicato=0",
    dataType: "html",

    //Inizio visualizzazione errori
    success: function(msg)
    {
      alert(msg);
    },
    error: function()
    {
      alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...");
    }
  });
}
```

my salva_doc_ajax.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['html']) && isset($_POST['pubblicato'])){
  $oggetto = $_POST['oggetto'];
  $html = $_POST['html'];
  $pubblicato = $_POST['pubblicato'];
  $oggetto = addslashes(htmlentities($oggetto));
  $html = addslashes(htmlentities($html));

    echo "Oggetto: $oggetto";
    echo "<br>HTML: $html";
    echo "<br>Pubblicato: $pubblicato";
}else{

    echo "Errore";

}
?>
```

I've tested that in 'htmlpure' and in 'oggetto' there is data...
everytime I run this js function I get "Errore" from the php page, like if I don't send $_POST variables...

Comment: I don't see any value for `"name"` passed in your ajax data, while it's mandatory in your PHP file: `if(isset($_POST['name']) && ...`

Comment: I assume `$_POST['name']` should be `$_POST['oggetto']`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in an ajax POST, your data should be an object. You are sending a query string for a GET request.

Also, as @Kaddath said, there is no name in your post.

See what you're getting by adding this line to the very top of `salva_doc_ajax.php` and comparing it to what you think you're getting:

`die(print_r($_POST));`